# Editing a dynamically created results set with html/php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm looking for a web design strategy that must be a common problem but I can't find any solutions.

I have an HTML page with search parameters.  On change of a parameter the page loads a results set into a page subsection via ajax.  Results come from a mysql database via php.  All good so far.

I then want to give the user the ability to edit some of the fields in the results set - eg check a "print" checkbox, or change a "discount" input value for each row of the results set.  The user then hits the 'go' button and I'll send the modified results to another php page for processing maybe in a session variable.  This is the bit I'm not sure about.

What's the best way to go about this?  Thanks.

Comment: At the time of displaying result, you should display result in input tag..like this..<input type="text" name="abc" value="<?php echo $your_value_from_db;?>"/>

Comment: Thanks.  Sort of figured that, but I have to do it for each row in the results set... not a problem but each <input> will be dynamically created so will need a dynamically created name I guess.  And then when I post the page   what's the best way to get all those dynamically created controls and pass the values to the next page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td contenteditable='true'>".$row['Row1']."</td>";
  echo "<td contenteditable='true'>".$row['Row2']."</td>";
  echo "<td contenteditable='true'>".$row['Row3']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

}
```

Try that Code and use the the sessions in every row to read the current data in the rows.

Comment: Ah... the "contenteditable" set me in the right direction.  Thanks.  Googling to find how to get the results back into the database.

Still keen to know how it would be done without HTML5 though.

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying data dynamically so obvious you have to display it using loop. No need of  dynamically created name. And on next page you can handle them as array or multidimensional array. You have to do bit of search regarding this.